# Don't see "Hello,Android" on emulator

Tags: android

I created Hello,Android application with TextView, not xml.
When I run it I don't see "Hello,Android", only wallpaper.
Any ideas, what is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It takes up to 2 minutes to have the run app rendered. Don't worry, just be patient.

You can leave the emulator running and run the app over and over again so it will not take that long after the first time.

I also found that starting the emulator from the command line is a lot faster, and you can just leave it running, and run the app from Eclipse; this way starting the app will not take long at all since your emulator has been running already.

I hope above is helpful...

Comment: Good comment, had the same problem (impatience)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Eclipse so the first question is Do you have an android phone connected to the computer? If so the "Hello, Android"-program will hopefully be running on that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I gues I know why I couldnt see "Hello, Android".
You just have to click on

1. "Home" Icon in the emulator
2. Select applications icon at the bottom of emulator desktop.
3. Lauch the helloAndroid application to see the message.

Hope this helps.

Lasantha